# Metodo Retorna Objeto, Como Recibirlo

Tags: c#, poo

tengo un método que me retorna un objeto

```
public CPunto PuntoMedio(CPunto a, CPunto b)
     {

        int xm = (a.x + b.x) / 2;
        int ym = (a.y + b.y) / 2;
        return new CPunto(xm, ym);
     }
```

mi duda es como recibir ese Return aquí donde lo quiero usar

```
 if (radbutpm.Checked)
                    {
                        CPunto PM;
                        PM = new CPunto(PT.PuntoMedio(LPuntos[posi1], LPuntos[posi2]));
                        txtresult.Text = Convert.ToString(PM);
                    }
```

Comment: Tu clase CPunto tiene un método ToString()??

Comment: Hola Gracias por comentar Pero ya lo solucione Gracias